# std::getline not producing correct output (c++)

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I'm doing a homework assignment in c++ and I could use a little help. I am not understanding why the following code isn't working as I want it. The object of the function I'm creating is to load a file and parse it into keys and values for a map while skipping blank lines and lines where the first character is a hastag. The file I'm reading from is below.

The problem is that my `nextToken` variable is not being delimited by the `'='` character. I mean, when I `cout nextToken`, it doesn't equal the string before the `'='` character. For example, the first two lines of the data file are

```
# Sample configuration/initialization file 
DetailedLog=1
```

I thought that the code I have should skip all the lines that begin with a hashtag (but it's only skipping the first line) and that `nextToken` would equal just `DetailedLog` (as opposed to `DetailedLog=1` or just equal to `1`).

In my output, some lines with a hashtag are skipped while some are not and I can't understand where `cout` is printing from since the `cout` statement I have should print `"nextToken: "` and then `nextToken`, but it's printing `nextToken` then `"nextToken: "` then what comes after the `'='` character from the data file.

Here's my code:

```
bool loadFile (string filename){
    ifstream forIceCream(filename);
    string nextToken;
    if (forIceCream.is_open()){
        while (getline(forIceCream, nextToken, '=')) {
            if (nextToken.empty() || nextToken[0] == '#') {
                continue;
            }
            cout << "nextToken: " << nextToken << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Data file reading from:

```
# Sample configuration/initialization file

DetailedLog=1

RunStatus=1

StatusPort=6090

StatusRefresh=10

Archive=1

LogFile=/tmp/logfile.txt

Version=0.1

ServerName=Unknown

FileServer=0

# IP addresses

PrimaryIP=192.168.0.13

SecondaryIP=192.168.0.10

# Random comment
```

Comment: Umm... just for starters... `getline` does not produce output `:)` Also, it would help if you post [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can insure your error isn't being generated in an unseen portion of your code.

Answer (score 2):

If the first two lines of your input file are:

```
# Sample configuration/initialization file
DetailedLog=1
```

Then, the call

```
getline(forIceCream, nextToken, '=')
```

will read everything up to the first `=` to `nextToken`. At the end of the line, the value of `nextToken` will be:

```
# Sample configuration/initialization file
DetailedLog
```

See the documentation of [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and pay attention to the first overload.

You need to change your strategy for processing the contents of the file a little bit.

1. Read the contents of the file line by line.
2. Process each line as you see fit.

Here's an updated version of your function.

```
bool loadFile (string filename)
{
   ifstream forIceCream(filename);
   if (forIceCream.is_open())
   {
      // Read the file line by line.
      string line;
      while ( getline(forIceCream, line) )
      {
         // Discard empty lines and lines starting with #.
         if (line.empty() || line[0] == '#')
         {
            continue;
         }

         // Now process the line using a istringstream.
         std::istringstream str(line);
         string nextToken;
         if ( getline(str, nextToken, '=') )
         {
            cout << "nextToken: " << nextToken << endl;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, some defects just jump out at me :) What can I say?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, you are kind.

Comment: Could you use forIceCream instead of the istringstream in the second getline?